# Como atribuir o resultado de connection.query em uma variável global?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou aprendendo utilizar o modulo `mysql` do node e me deparei uma situação de não conseguir atribuir o resultado a uma variável global, segue meu código:

```
let data = 0

  connection.query(query, (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('An error ocurred performing the query.')
      console.log(err)
      return
    }

    data = rows
  })
```

se eu printar a variável `data` o resultado é zero, como eu atribuo o resultado a ela?

obs: utilizei este exemplo da documentação.

Comment: `data = rows` dentro da função irá atribuir o valor a `data`, mas é importante ter em mente que isso é uma função assíncrona. Logo pode não funcionar, dependendo de onde e como utiliza esse `data`. Compo exemplo, essa consulta pode hipoteticamente levar digamos 5 segundos a executar, e entretanto já o resto do arquivo já foi processado e por isso já utilizou o `data` sem ter sido atribuído. Regra geral a solução que pretende é outra mas é difícil de ajudar sem ver como está a utilizar o `data`. Nesse exemplo simples bastaria usar o `data` dentro de `query`

Comment: Acabei de verificar, é isso mesmo a função leva um tempo e o meu código de printar executa antes da atribuição, obrigado